# Then why are we closing "is possible to uninstall an operating system?"?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

I really hate that first close reason. It doesn't tell me anything and too much. Doesn't tell me what is wrong, nor it tells me exactly what is wrong. Can somebody explain to me what part of the [help center](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic) says that my question is off-topic?

Let me rant for a bit: if you are going to use that close reason, give a clue about how the post could be fixed.

The question in topic [Why is not feasible to uninstall an operating system the same way it is installed?](https://superuser.com/q/693758/235569)

Comment: If you're just here for ranting, this is not the right place. If you have something to discuss in a *constructive* manner, your thoughts and questions are welcome.

Comment: @slhck I'm not ranting, I'm asking politely (if you left out the "darn") which of the several "don't ask" of the help center is the reason why my question is being closed.

Comment: I'll cite you: "Let me rant for a bit…" — Also, there's no specific reason for everything in our Help center. You'd have to ask the users who voted to close using that reason. I gave you a reason why this question is not acceptable in the comments on the OP.

Comment: @slhck I'll give you that, but remember that is not an emotional outburst of my part (well maybe a little). And with that you affirm my thinking that I'm unable to fix the question if the close reason is so vague, which is why I want it removed.

Comment: We cannot remove the standard reason, simply because we cannot include specific reasons for every imaginable topic that is out of scope. If you are dissatisfied with the closing of a question of yours, you can always come to Meta to ask for specifics, but generally the default reason has its merits, so it won't be removed.

Answer (score 5):

Relax, it's just one person casting their one vote.

Comment: Remember that that normally doesn't matter as most of voter just blindly cast their votes.

Comment: @Braiam - ah...so little faith. I think most voters take time to review the content and comments. I will say, I have been swayed on a compelling comment. My concern is that the comments will get into a debate instead of enhancing clarity. but that is just my opinion.

Comment: @CarlB nah, that's not the main issue. Is my incapability to understand why my question is "off-topic" since the close reason is unuseful and seems more like a wild-card against questions that voters don't like.

Comment: @Braiam did you even read the close reason? It doesn't say "off topic", it says "primarily opinion based". The question isn't technical or looking to solve a problem, it's looking to arbitrarily define an arbitrary concept that has no practical value.  To [quote the help center](http://superuser.com/help/dont-ask), "You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face. Chatty, open-ended questions diminish the usefulness of our site and push other questions off the front page."

Comment: @nhinkle sorry, but if you read the comments of [techie007](http://superuser.com/questions/693758/is-possible-to-uninstall-an-operating-system#comment881974_693758) the question wasn't being closed because is opinion based but off topic. Also, the close reason don't tell me what is wrong, is a plain "SIU, we don't want your question here". But worries not, I'm planing to write something more *useful*.

Comment: @nhinkle the close was done by slhck as opinion based (which with his explanation I believe he's right) and he offered a helpful advice about how I can fix my question.

Comment: @Braiam it's off topic _because_ it's opinion based, essentially. At any rate, I think you've learned how to improve the question now, so the goal of putting it on hold has been achieved.